# Why Is What God Thinks Different from What God Says to Noah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-noach

In [Genesis 8:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.9.8-17?lang=bi&aliyot=0) **God thinks** to himself:

> וַיָּ֣רַח יְהוָה֮ אֶת־רֵ֣יחַ הַנִּיחֹחַ֒ וַיֹּ֨אמֶר יְהוָ֜ה אֶל־לִבּ֗וֹ לֹֽא־אֹ֠סִף לְקַלֵּ֨ל ע֤וֹד אֶת־הָֽאֲדָמָה֙ בַּעֲב֣וּר הָֽאָדָ֔ם כִּ֠י יֵ֣צֶר לֵ֧ב הָאָדָ֛ם רַ֖ע מִנְּעֻרָ֑יו וְלֹֽא־אֹסִ֥ף ע֛וֹד לְהַכּ֥וֹת אֶת־כָּל־חַ֖י כַּֽאֲשֶׁ֥ר עָשִֽׂיתִי׃
>
> The LORD smelled the pleasing odor, and the LORD said to Himself: “Never again will I doom the earth because of man, since the devisings of man’s mind are evil from his youth; nor will I ever again destroy every living being, as I have done.

Then a few lines later in Genesis 9:11 (same link as above), **God says** to Noah:

> וַהֲקִמֹתִ֤י אֶת־בְּרִיתִי֙ אִתְּכֶ֔ם וְלֹֽא־יִכָּרֵ֧ת כָּל־בָּשָׂ֛ר ע֖וֹד מִמֵּ֣י הַמַּבּ֑וּל וְלֹֽא־יִהְיֶ֥ה ע֛וֹד מַבּ֖וּל לְשַׁחֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃
>
> I will maintain My covenant with you: never again shall all flesh be cut off by the waters of a flood, and never again shall there be a flood to destroy the earth.”

**Paraphrasing, God thinks, I will never destroy all humankind; God says, I will never destroy all humankind with a flood.**

The Lubavitcher Rebbe (an exceptional Torah scholar) maintains (see "concise" in the index of "Torah Studies a parsha anthology" for multiple references) that extra or superfluous words are avoided in the Torah.  Hence, adding the words "with a flood" to what God says to Noah must be significant.  What God says to Noah is much more qualified or limited than what He thought earlier.

**Why the difference?  What does this difference teach us?**

Comment: Is there a difference? I do not see a difference at all.

Comment: @TurkHill there's a significant difference. If you only say that you won't destroy the world by flood, then you may still destroy the world another way. If Hashem meant He won't destroy the world at all, why differentiate when speaking to Noach and leaving a kind of caveat?

Comment: @Harel13 Nope, no difference. whether it's a promise not to destroy the world with flood or not, it's a promise not to destroy it.

Comment: @TurkHill agree to disagree then.

Comment: IMHO, you should include Shmos Rabbah that the Egyptians counted on that promise not to destroy by water.

Comment: Why do you assume that what God "says" should necessarily equal to what He "thinks"? Did you see sources that necessitate God to be honest or frank with humans? By me it's the opposite, God never fully reveals His plans or intentions to humans.

Comment: @AlBerko sure, but then why even write Hashem's thoughts in the first place, and in wording that's different from what He eventually said to Noach?

Comment: "why even write Hashem's thoughts in the first place" is a great question to ask on this site. Go ahead, I guarantee my +1.

Comment: @AlBerko Thanks. I'm just not sure it's quite that different from this question, unless asked in a general sense, which would mean that I'd have to find more places where this occurs, if there are.

Comment: This happens a lot. You ask a question presuming something that on second thought is not so apparent.

Comment: @AlBerko Note however that the Torah is written as economically as possible.  Things are said as directly as possible, extra words are avoided.  Why then, if the aim is to say "I will not destroy humankind", are the extra words "by flood" added?

Comment: Your *"Torah is written as economically as possible. Things are said as directly as possible, extra words are avoided."* is factually wrong (again), you assume the conclusion again. The gemmorah says that God loves "שיחת עבדי אבות" so much He doesn't care to repeat it several times with no practical implications, also the Talmudic discussion of "דברה תורה כלשון בנ"א" proves that certain words ARE excessive.

Comment: @AlBerko, nevertheless, כל היכא דאיכא למדרש דרשינן (see, for example, Tosafos to Sotah 24a, ד"ה ורבי יונתן).

Comment: The Ohr Hachaim Hakadosh has a long discussion of this ad loc, and he deals with this question too. I don't have the time to write it up at present, though.

Answer (score 2):

The Gemora Shevous 36A says the reason the promise not to destroy the world with a mabul was repeated twice was to give that promises the status of an oath. It is a complex question in the Rishonim about the parameters of that oath (e.g. was it only an oath about a mabul?)but that is why it was repeated twice to begin with.

See the Ohr HaChaim on the second posuk who discusses the Gemara and   indirectly touches on this question.

Hashem did not tell Noach anything different than his original promise.  Rather he was clarifying the parameters of his oath in relation to floods. Not only he will never destroy all of mankind again even if he will bring a flood to destroy some places it will not have the effect of destruction on the land that the Mabul which Noach experienced  did. לֹֽא־יִהְיֶ֥ה ע֛וֹד מַבּ֖וּל ***לְשַׁחֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ***

Comment: So is your conclusion that God promised not destroy humankind by plague, fire, flood, pestilence, or any other means?

Comment: That is what the Ohr HaChaim says

Answer (score 1):

The Akivian methodology suggests that what G-d "says" and "thinks" are two different things. Whenever the Bible repeats or adds a word, it must be there to teach a lesson.

Rabbi Ishmael disagreed. He felt that “the Torah [which is intended for humans] speaks in human language.” Thus, the Torah repeats itself for emphasis to make a point. It may even do so to make a flowery or poetic point. We should not read anything new into these repetitions (which are many). If G-d intended to teach an additional lesson, it would not be hidden in repetition, it would have been an explicit statement.

Referring to your question with Rabbi Ishmael's view shows that nothing is being added. Genesis 8:21 and 9:11 says the same thing. G-d will not destroy the world again. There is no difference at all between those two verses.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on your comment.

Comment: @ron Your welcome.